# ReferenceError: primordials is not defined - why?

Tags: javascript, svg, npm, gruntjs

I installed the gunticon package. Currently on osx 10146, grunt 104, grunticon 232, node 12141.

When I launch the grunt command on a grunticon folder, I keep getting ReferenceError: primordials is not defined. Also

```
Warning: Task "grunticon:icons" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

how to solve?

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"} (current: {"node":"12.14.1","npm":"6.13.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: got@5.7.1
npm WARN ico-svg@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN ico-svg@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ grunt-grunticon@2.3.2
added 494 packages from 281 contributors and audited 11312 packages in 22.115s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 46 vulnerabilities (22 low, 9 moderate, 14 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
➜  ico-svg grunt                                
>> ReferenceError: primordials is not defined


➜  ico-svg grunt                                     
Loading "grunticon.js" tasks...ERROR
>> ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
Warning: Task "grunticon:icons" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: I've ran into this problem, downgrade your node to version 9 as you're gruntjs is probably very out of date, in my situation, it was gulp but downgrading resolved this issue.

Comment: I wouldn't like to downgrade node, though.

Comment: If you look in your logs, it tells you your node and npm is not supported.